# Using memcpy across different platforms which have different endianess

Tags: c++, endianness, memcpy

I am writing a function which copys data from a uint32_t into a std::vector. This program will be used across different platforms which have different endianess ( mainly LE but some BE)

Currently I am using this:

```
std:vector<uint8_t> Decryption::GenerateIvForBlock(uint32_t blockNumber)
{
    std:vector<uint8_t> ivInput(AES128_KEY_BYTE_LENGTH, 0);

// Some code
if (///////)
{
    memcpy(&ivInput[0], &blockNumber, sizeof(blockNumber));
}
}
```

currently the behavior is different across the different endian typed platforms, even though blockNumber is the same across the platforms.
Unfortunately I cant very easily test the Big endian systems so I struggling to work out a solution.

Comment: Then you should stop using `memcpy`? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: For such situation the `ntohx()` / `htonx()` function family might come in handy. Don't use `memcpy()`.

Comment: The data is being moved between systems. To test at least the little endian side, write a program that mocks a Big endian system by providing data to your little endian system in big endian format. This is only half the problem, but getting the little endian side right will give you the hints you need to be reasonably confident your Big endian side will be mostly right.

Comment: on gnu you have     bswap_16(x); bswap_32(x); bswap_64(x);
 in byteswap.h

Comment: @OznOg Unconditional byteswapping won't help. One would first need to figure out if it's needed, possibly using the C++20 test `if(std::endian::native != std::endian::big)` but there's also the tricky `mixed` endian to take care of.

Answer (score 1):

As πάντα ῥεῖ suggested, the `ntohx()`/`htonx()` functions can help you with converting 16 and 32 bit unsigned integrals from network byte order to host byte order and back.

There's been some drafts for including templates for `ntoh()` and `hton()` in a C++ `<net>` header but afaik, no suceess. You will probably find the C functions in `<Winsock2.h>` or `<arpa/inet.h>` so you can create templates yourself. Example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#ifdef _WIN32
 #include <Winsock2.h>
#else
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

template <class T>
T hton(T host) noexcept = delete;

template <>
uint8_t hton(uint8_t host) noexcept {
    return host;
}

template <>
uint16_t hton(uint16_t host) noexcept {
    return htons(host);
}

template <>
uint32_t hton(uint32_t host) noexcept {
    return htonl(host);
}

template <class T>
T ntoh(T network) noexcept = delete;

template <>
uint8_t ntoh(uint8_t network) noexcept {
    return network;
}

template <>
uint16_t ntoh(uint16_t network) noexcept {
    return ntohs(network);
}

template <>
uint32_t ntoh(uint32_t network) noexcept {
    return ntohl(network);
}
```

With those in place, you could create a wrapper class template for your vectors with stream operators to save and restore the data. Below is a very basic example. Add operators etc. as needed.

```
template <typename T>
class Data {
    std::vector<T> m_data;
public:
    Data() : m_data{} {}

    template< class... Args >
    auto emplace_back( Args&&... args ) {
        return m_data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void reserve(typename std::vector<T>::size_type size) {
        m_data.reserve(size);
    }
    bool operator==(const Data& o) {
        return m_data == o.m_data;
    }

    template <typename V>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Data<V>&);
    template <typename V>
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Data<V>&);
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Data<T>& d) {
    // write the number of entries first
    const uint32_t count = hton(static_cast<const uint32_t>(d.m_data.size()));
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&count), sizeof(count));
    // write all the entries, converted to network byte order
    for(auto v : d.m_data) {
        v = hton(v);
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Data<T>& d) {
    // read the number of entries first
    uint32_t count;
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count), sizeof(count));
    d.m_data.resize(ntoh(count));
    // read all the entries and convert to host byte order
    for(auto& v : d.m_data) {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
        v = ntoh(v);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    Data<unsigned> orig;
    Data<unsigned> copy;
    std::stringstream ss;
    orig.reserve(1024*1024);
    for(unsigned i=0; i<1024*1024; ++i) orig.emplace_back(i);
    ss << orig; // save to stream
    // the data in 'ss' is now in network byte order
    ss >> copy; // restore from stream
    if(orig==copy) std::cout << "happy\n";
}
```